# Long division - Presentation of answer

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question which asks me to divide one polynomial by another, I use long division and my way of presenting the answer is as shown on the very bottom of the sheet, however, the way that I was shown in lecture was different as shown above my answer at the bottom. Isn't this wrong as its is equal to the polynomial that is the numerator and not succinctly giving the answer to the division? Am I missing something completely here?

[image]

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are rational or real numbers, we might say that $A/B = q + r/B$, where $q$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder (this is your second presentation, more or less).  Alternatively, we could say that $A = Bq + r$, with the same notation (this is your first presentation).  Notice that both of these presentations are complete grammatical sentences, with the verb begin "=" ("is equal to").  Neither of your proposed solutions is a complete sentence, so it is hard to understand what you are saying (you have no verb).

Comment: Oh I see, so the second way $A=Bq+r$ is also correct just a different way of "saying" it?